# Excel: count amount of characters

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to calculate a price by single character. In my example I have 110 parts that are numbered, so this means I have:

- 9 parts with one character (1 > 9)
- 90 parts with two characters (10 > 99)
- 11 parts with three characters (100 > 110)
  Thus there are 222 characters for this price.

Is there a way to calculate this with a (nested) formula ? I've been thinking about since a few days and can't come with a solid & modular formula.
See "manual"-Excel calculation here below.
[image: Example]
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Sorry, I for one don't understand your question at all. Can you provide samples of the data you are trying to count / sum based upon this single character, and some examples?

Comment: @JvdV understood my question (and already gave me the answer too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean:

```
=SUM(LEN(SEQUENCE(110)))
```

Or for non-Microsoft 365 versions:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(ROW(A1:INDEX(A:A,110))))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the number of characters of a list of values that is **not** a continuous sequence starting with 1 up to e.g. 110, then you can do it with the following formula:

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(list,">=1",list,"<=9")*1,COUNTIFS(list,">=10",list,"<=99")*2,COUNTIFS(list,">=100",list,"<=999")*3)
```

**Note**: the term "list" is just a name that refers to a range of Excel cells.